# multiple isNaN in a if else javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

So I created a javascript that is gonna draw up a number of divs and style them according to what the value of the input is. The problem is, when I try to draw up a warning that you have to put in a number and not anything else. At the moment I cant seem to get it to create the figures at all, it will only display the warning that the value is not a number..

My code:

```
function genFigures(){
    var numberFig = numberFigInput.value;
    var widthValue = figWidthInput.value;
    var heightValue = figHeightInput.value;
    var colorValue = figRgbInput.value;
    var leftValue = figPosLeftInput.value;
    var topValue = figPosTopInput.value;

    if (numberFig >= 1001){
        alert("You need to input a value between 1 and 1000!");

    }if (isNaN(numberFigInput) && isNaN(figWidthInput) && isNaN(figWidthInput) && isNaN(figPosLeftInput) && isNaN(figPosTopInput)){
        alert("You have to insert a number!");

    }else{
        for(var amount = 0; amount < numberFig; amount++){
            myFigures.innerHTML += "<div></div>"

            var figStyle = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

            for(var i = 0; i < figStyle.length; i++){
            figStyle[i].style.width = widthValue +"px";
            figStyle[i].style.height = heightValue +"px";
            figStyle[i].style.background = "rgb(" + colorValue + ")";
            figStyle[i].style.left = leftValue +"px";
            figStyle[i].style.top = topValue +"px";

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do realise you are using isNaN on the element and not the value right, and did you mean to use an `else if` for the second if?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot why you created additional vars ;)

It should be

```
if (isNaN(numberFig) && isNaN(widthValue) && isNaN(...) && isNaN(leftValue) && isNaN(topValue)){
        alert("You have to insert a number!");
```

Instead of `...` there would be `colorValue` or `heightValue`, I don't know exactly, because you repeated `figWidthInput` two times.

Comment: so I changed it to the variable names like you said, but now nothing is happening when i insert letters in the boxes

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN()` is not the proper way to test in user input is a number. You have to use `parseInt()`, like this: `parseInt(figWidthInput, 10)`.

Comment: isNaN is the proper way, using parseInt on a non number will give you NaN which you will then have to test for, so might as well use isNaN in the first place. OP's problem is that they are testing against the element and not the value of the input.